# IE8 align span vertically center above image using css only?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I want to align span tag vertically center with respect to image tag and above image in IE8.

I have a DOM like this:

```
    <div class="parent">
      <img src="pathToImage"/>
      <span>Align this text to vertical center</span>
   </div>
```

Good answer is appreciated.

Comment: Posted an answer, though after reread my answer, and your question, I start wonder: What do you mean with _above image_?

Comment: I mean text should display above image like using position or negative margin..Got it?

Comment: So why is the span _after_ the image in the markup and how is the vertical space created where the span should center?

Comment: Actually the whole DOM is gnerated dynamically from backend so i want text stays on the image and vertically center to that image, I done it in all beowser but facing problem in IE8.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If span has a known height(how much text/lines), you could float down the image and let span move into the area freed by image :

```css
.parent:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  height: 2em;/* at least enough for one line of text */
}
img {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
  <span>Align this text to vertical center</span>
</div>
```

To filter IE8 you can use [the conditionnal comments from IE toolbox](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)  `<!--[if IE8]><style>/* styles here */</style><[endif]-->` and for any older browsers,  you can overide this float behavior via flex:

```css
.parent:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  height: 2em;
}
img {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
  <span>Align this text to vertical center</span>
</div>
```

...

I still do not see the point of it ?

Another way to filter IE8

```css
body:before {
  content:'IE8';
  }
body::before {
  content:'NOT IE8';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can come up with, using the existing markup, is this, using `position: absolute` to center it

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.parent span {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 22px;
  width: 150px;
  left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <span>Align to vertical center</span>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

The only CSS way with dynamic text (1 or more lines), is to combine `display: table` and `position: absolute`.

Stack snippet

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.parent > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.parent > div > div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Align to vertical center,<br>
      even with 2 lines</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but it has some issue when text is in single and double line both. Anyway thanks for help. ;-)

Comment: @bherumehta Was going over some older answers and found this. Decided to update with the hope to get an accept :)